# Recursively calling in a show function

Tags: haskell, recursion, show

I am taking in a data type MyList which has a tail with list and a head.  Need to turn it into a reversed string like the haskell data type list.

```
showList :: MyList a -> String
showlist (MyList h t) =  show(showlist(t) ++ show( h : [] ))
```

I am getting out this craziness for showList [1,2,3]

```
"\"[3][2]\"[1]"
```

Comment: `showList [1,2,3]` doesn't appear to be even well-typed (unless you're using `-XOverloadedLists`). Please always add a [MCVE] to questions about errors or unexpected output, so we actually know what you're doing.

Comment: `show` is not equivalent to `id` when given a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically calling `show` two times: you don't need that, once you got a string that's all what is required to implement `show`. So instead of this:

```
Prelude> show [1,2,3]
"[1,2,3]"
```

you are getting:

```
Prelude> show $ show [1,2,3]
"\"[1,2,3]\""
```

And that's because in order to print `"` Haskell needs to escape those with `\`.

Let's go back to your definition, you are trying to define a function of type `MyList a -> String`, so basically we'll need to call `show` only over the elements of type `a` (I'd assume `h` is of type `a`, and this type is an instance of `Show`):

```
showList :: (Show a) => MyList a -> String
showList Nil = ""
showlist (MyList h t) =  showlist(t) ++ show(h : [])
```

I'm assuming your list type is something like:

```
data MyList a = Nil | MyList a (MyList a)
```

So you'll get (I don't know why you are reversing the list when showing):

```
Prelude> showList (MyList 1 (MyList 2 Nil))
"[2][1]"
```

If you want, you can improve a little bit your show function by using `,`:

```
showList :: (Show a) => MyList a -> String
showList Nil = ""
showlist (MyList h t) =  show h ++ "," ++ showlist t
```

Hence, you'll get:

```
Prelude> showList (MyList 1 (MyList 2 Nil))
"1,2,"
```

I leave you as an exercise how to properly place `,`,`[` and `]` to print likewise:

```
"[1,2]"
```